# Change dapp gateway

Tags: decentralized-applications, multiversx, tatum.io

How can I change the MultiversX dapp gateway? I want to use tatum.io in exchange of gateway.multiversx.com but with the MultiversX dapp template https://github.com/multiversx/mx-template-dapp I don't know how to do it!

```
  <DappProvider
    environment={environment}
    customNetworkConfig={{ 
      name: 'customConfig',
      gatewayAddress:'https://api-eu1.tatum.io/v3/egld/node/id',
      apiTimeout: 10000 
    }}
    completedTransactionsDelay={200}
  >
```

gateAddress is not a valid key, only apiAddress so it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the interface of the customNetworkConfig:

```js
export interface CustomNetworkType {
    id?: string;
    chainId?: string;
    name?: string;
    egldLabel?: string;
    egldDenomination?: string;
    decimals?: string;
    gasPerDataByte?: string;
    walletConnectDeepLink?: string;
    walletConnectBridgeAddresses?: string[];
    walletAddress?: string;
    apiAddress?: string;
    explorerAddress?: string;
    skipFetchFromServer?: boolean;
    apiTimeout?: string;
}
```

As you see, there isn't a `gatewayAddress` variable.
Could you explain us what you want to do by changing the gateway?